# Render metabox gallery in frontend

Tags: functions, metabox, gallery, front-end

I'm building two metabox galleries on the same page with the help of a tutorial. The code works fine. However the galleries are automatically displayed after the content on the front end.

What I would like to do is to display each gallery wherever I want in my template page, not automatically after the content.

Here is the PHP code in my functions.php:

```
/**
 *  Sortable WordPress Gallery class to create gallery metabox and save it
 */
class Sortable_WordPress_Gallery {

    /**
     * Unique ID of the metabox
     * @var string
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * Metabox Title
     * @var string
     */
    protected $title = '';

    /**
     * Metabox Context
     * @var string
     */
    protected $context = 'advanced';

    /**
     * Metabox Priority
     * @var string
     */
    protected $priority = 'high';

    /**
     * Hook into the appropriate actions when the class is constructed.
     */
    public function __construct( $id, $title = '', $context = 'advanced', $priority = 'high'  ) {

        // ID is required
        if( $id == '' ) {
            return;
        }

        $this->id = $id;

        // Create title from ID if not provided
        if( $title == '' ) {
            $this->title = ucfirst( $id );
        } else {
            $this->title = $title;
        }

        // Only valid context can be changed
        $available_context = array(
            'advanced',
            'side',
            'normal');
        if( in_array( $context, $available_context ) ) {
            $this->context = $context;
        }

        // Only valid priorty can be changed
        $available_priority = array(
            'default',
            'high',
            'low');
        if( in_array( $priority, $available_priority ) ) {
            $this->priority = $priority;
        }

        add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array( $this, 'add_meta_box' ) );
        add_action( 'save_post',      array( $this, 'save' ) );
        add_filter( 'the_content', array( $this, 'render' ) );
    }

    /**
     * Adds the meta box container.
     */
    public function add_meta_box( $post_type ) {

        // Limit meta box to certain post types.
        // Can be extended using filter 'sortable_wordpress_gallery_post_types' or
        // using a dynamic filter 'sortable_wordpress_gallery_METABOX-ID_post_types'
        $post_types = apply_filters( 'sortable_wordpress_gallery_post_types', array( 'page' ) );
        $post_types = apply_filters( 'sortable_wordpress_gallery_' . $this->id .  '_post_types',  $post_types );

        if ( in_array( $post_type, $post_types ) ) {
            add_meta_box(
                $this->id,
                $this->title,
                array( $this, 'render_meta_box_content' ),
                $post_type,
                $this->context,
                $this->priority
                );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Render Meta Box content.
     *
     * @param WP_Post $post The post object.
     */
    public function render_meta_box_content( $post ) {


        // Add an nonce field so we can check when saving
        wp_nonce_field( $this->id . '_metabox', $this->id . '_metabox_nonce' );

      // Get the gallery saved data
        $sortable_gallery = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_' . $this->id . '_sortable_wordpress_gallery', true );

        ?>
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th style="vertical-align: top;">
                    <?php _e( 'Slider Images', 'your_text_domain' ); ?>
                </th>
                <td>
                  <!-- Creating a dynamic ID using the metabox ID for JavaScript-->
                    <ul id="<?php echo $this->id; ?>_sortable_wordpress_gallery" class="sortable_wordpress_gallery">
                        <?php
                        // Getting all the image IDs by creating an array from string ( 1,3,5 => array( 1, 3, 5) )
                        $gallery = explode(",", $sortable_gallery );

                      // If there is any ID, create the image for it
                        if( count( $gallery ) > 0 && $gallery[0] != '' ) {
                            foreach ( $gallery as $attachment_id ) {

                              // Create a LI elememnt
                                $output = '<li tabindex="0" role="checkbox" aria-label="' . get_the_title( $attachment_id ) . '" aria-checked="true" data-id="' . $attachment_id . '" class="attachment save-ready selected details">';
                                 // Create a container for the image. (Copied from the WP Media Library Modal to use the same styling)
                                  $output .= '<div class="attachment-preview js--select-attachment type-image subtype-jpeg portrait">';
                                    $output .= '<div class="thumbnail">';

                                      $output .= '<div class="centered">';
                                       // Get the URL to that image thumbnail
                                        $output .= '<img src="'  . wp_get_attachment_thumb_url( $attachment_id ) . '" draggable="false" alt="">';
                                      $output .= '</div>';

                                    $output .= '</div>';

                                  $output .= '</div>';
                                // Add the button to remove this image if wanted (we set the data-gallery to target the correct gallery if there are more than one)
                                  $output .= '<button type="button" data-gallery="#' . $this->id . '_sortable_wordpress_gallery" class="button-link check remove-sortable-wordpress-gallery-image" tabindex="0"><span class="media-modal-icon"></span><span class="screen-reader-text">Deselect</span></button>';

                                $output .= '</li>';
                                echo $output;
                            }
                        }
                        ?>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- Hidden input used to save the gallery image IDs into the database -->
                    <!-- We are also creating dynamic IDs here so that we can easily target them in JavaScript -->
                    <input type="hidden" id="<?php echo $this->id; ?>_sortable_wordpress_gallery_input" name="_<?php echo $this->id; ?>_sortable_wordpress_gallery" value="<?php echo $sortable_gallery; ?>" />
                    <!-- Button used to open the WordPress Media Library Modal -->
                    <button type="button" class="button button-primary add-sortable-wordpress-gallery" data-gallery="#<?php echo $this->id; ?>_sortable_wordpress_gallery"><?php _e( 'Add Images', 'your_text_domain' ); ?></button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <?php
    }


    /**
     * Save the meta when the post is saved.
     *
     * @param int $post_id The ID of the post being saved.
     */
    public function save( $post_id ) {

        /*
         * We need to verify this came from the our screen and with proper authorization,
         * because save_post can be triggered at other times.
         */

        // Check if our nonce is set.
        if ( ! isset( $_POST[ $this->id . '_metabox_nonce'] ) ) {
            return $post_id;
        }

        $nonce = $_POST[ $this->id . '_metabox_nonce'];

        // Verify that the nonce is valid.
        if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, $this->id . '_metabox' ) ) {
            return $post_id;
        }

        /*
         * If this is an autosave, our form has not been submitted,
         * so we don't want to do anything.
         */
        if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
            return $post_id;
        }

        // Check the user's permissions.
        if ( 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {
            if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) ) {
                return $post_id;
            }
        } else {
            if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
                return $post_id;
            }
        }

        /* OK, it's safe for us to save the data now. */
        $gallery = sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ '_' . $this->id . '_sortable_wordpress_gallery' ] );

        // Update the meta field.
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_' . $this->id . '_sortable_wordpress_gallery', $gallery );

    }


    /**
   * Rendering the gallery
   */
  public function render( $content ) {
    global $post;

    // Get our registered post types
    $post_types = apply_filters( 'sortable_wordpress_gallery_post_types', array( 'page' ) );
    $post_types = apply_filters( 'sortable_wordpress_gallery_' . $this->id .  '_post_types',  $post_types );

    // Get current post type
    $this_post_type = get_post_type( $post );

    // If the current post type is also a registered post type, create the gallery
    if( in_array( $this_post_type, $post_types ) ) {
        // Get all the image IDs
        $gallery_images = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_' . $this->id . '_sortable_wordpress_gallery', true );
            if( $gallery_images != '' ) {
              // If the data retrieved is not empty, create an array
                $gallery_images_array = explode( ',', $gallery_images );
                //Create a gallery container with the 3 column layout
                $content .= '<div class="gallery" style="display: flex;">';
                // For each image ID, create the gallery image
                foreach ( $gallery_images_array as $image_id ) {

                $html = wp_get_attachment_image( $image_id );
            if( $html == '' ) {
              continue;
            }

            $content .= '<div class="gallery-item">';
              $content .= '<a href="' . get_permalink( $image_id ) . '" target="_blank">';
                $content .= $html;
              $content .= '</a>';
            $content .= '</div>';
          }

                $content .= '</div>';
            }
     }

        return $content;
    }


}



/**
 * WordPress Gallery Factory
 */
class Sortable_WordPress_Galleries {

    /**
     * Gallery Defaults
     * @var array
     */
    protected $gallery_defaults = array(
            'class' => 'Sortable_WordPress_Gallery',
            'id' => '',
            'title' => '',
            'context' => '',
            'priority' => '' );

    /**
     * Galleries that have been registered to use
     * @var array
     */
    protected $galleries = array();

    /**
     * Loaded galleries (Gallery objects)
     * @var array
     */
    protected $loaded_galleries = array();

    /**
     * Constructor method
     */
    public function __construct() {

        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'collect_galleries') );
        add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'admin_scripts' ) );
        add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'create_galleries' ) );
        add_filter( 'the_content', array( $this, 'render_galleries' ) );

    }

    /**
     * Enqueuing admin scripts and styles
     */
    /*
    public function admin_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'sortable-gallery-admin-js', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ). 'admin.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
            wp_enqueue_style( 'sortable-gallery-admin-css', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ). 'admin.css' );
    }*/
    public function admin_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'sortable-gallery-admin-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/gallery-multiple-metabox/js/admin.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
            wp_enqueue_style( 'sortable-gallery-admin-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/gallery-multiple-metabox/css/admin.css' );
    }

    /**
    * Collect galleries passed to our filter
    */
    public function collect_galleries() {

        $this->galleries = apply_filters( 'sortable_wordpress_galleries', $this->galleries );

    }


    /**
     * Hook our method load_galleries on edit post screens
     */
    public function create_galleries() {
        add_action( 'load-post.php',     array( $this, 'load_galleries' ) );
            add_action( 'load-post-new.php', array( $this, 'load_galleries' ) );

    }

    /**
    * Create gallery objects to create metaboxes
    */
    public function load_galleries() {

        foreach ( $this->galleries as $gallery ) {
            $gallery = wp_parse_args( $gallery, $this->gallery_defaults );
            $class = $gallery['class'];
            if( $class != '' ) {
                $this->loaded_galleries[] = new $class( $gallery['id'], $gallery['title'], $gallery['context'], $gallery['priority'] );
            }

        }
    }


    /**
     * Load all the galleries and render each gallery
     */
    public function render_galleries($content) {
        $this->load_galleries();

        foreach ( $this->loaded_galleries as $gallery ) {

            $content = $gallery->render( $content );

        }

        return $content;
    }
}
new Sortable_WordPress_Galleries();


add_filter( 'sortable_wordpress_galleries', 'add_sortable_gallery' );
function add_sortable_gallery( $galleries ) {
    
    // Gallery metabox #1
    $galleries[] = array(
        'class' => 'Sortable_WordPress_Gallery',
        'id' => 'post-metabox',
        'title' => 'Sortable Gallery'
    );
    
    // Gallery metabox #2
    $galleries[] = array(
        'class' => 'Sortable_WordPress_Gallery',
        'id' => 'post-metabox-2',
        'title' => 'Sortable Gallery-2'
    );

    return $galleries;
}
```

I'm struggling to find the way how to remove the rendering gallery out of `the_content();` and insert the rendering code inside my template.

Thank you.

Comment: You added render method  to "the_content" filter.  `add_filter( 'the_content', array( $this, 'render' ) );`. That's why you see gallery with `the_content`. Perhaps it's possible to add this render method as shortcode. Or you want something else?

Comment: Thank you @anton, you're right. I removed it and now the the gallery doesn't show up inside `the_content();`